# What is this symbol? (assumed compliance mark like CE / FCC)

Tags: identification, symbol, compliance

So Raspberry Pi have a new model out (the [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero-w-joins-family/)). Having taken a look at the photos, I see that on the reverse, where the CE and FCC compliance marks are shown, there is another symbol. It's hard to describe - something like a "T" with a parallel bar over the top enclosed by a three-quarter circle and a horizontal lightning bolt above the "T" but inside the partial circle.

Here's a picture:

[image: Photograph of reverse of Raspberry Pi Zero W]

and a close-up:

[image: Unknown symbol on reverse of Raspberry Pi Zero W]

Does anyone know what this symbol represents? My guess would be another compliance mark.

Comment: Worth to mention: What you call the "CE mark" is actually not the real one since the C and the E are too close together. The one you see one the board is jokingly called "China Export": https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/CE_marks.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that - think it's an oversight on their front as the [original Pi Zero](https://hackadaycom.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/raspberry_pi_quarter.jpg?w=549) has a correct mark. And that image referring to "China Export" is actually from the Raspberry Pi website itself! See [this comment](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero-w-joins-family/#comment-1271901) for more.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was wondering this myself, however some fairly extensive image digging revealed that it’s something approximate to the Japanese equivalent of the FCC certification mark, sometimes called **Giteki**. Japanese law seems to prescribe that radio devices should have this mark to be used in Japan.

http://incompliancemag.com/article/wireless-certification-in-the-land-of-the-rising-sun/

Comment: there's a nice Q&A on it here - http://www.tele.soumu.go.jp/e/adm/monitoring/illegal/monitoring_qa/purchase/purchase.htm apparently this mark has been around since 1995! +1 for your research

Comment: Nice find by @JImDearden, that Q&A reveals the old style Giteki mark too. [image](http://www.tele.soumu.go.jp/e/adm/monitoring/illegal/monitoring_qa/purchase/__icsFiles/artimage/2009/02/01/c_giteki_mar/giteki_old.jpg)

Comment: Also good to know - the name used in that Q&A is the "Technical Conformity Mark".

Comment: It is a "giteki" mark for sure! A Japanese Wireless Communications mark, to ensure the product meets Nippon's standards.